# How can I edit elasticsearch.yml on kubernetes pods, with a statefulset, or something similar?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, yaml, backup

I have to edit elasticsearch.yml in order to create a backup (setting the path.repo like this is necessary):
`path.repo: /mnt/backup`

But I have elasticsearch running on Kubernetes, and I would like to set the path.repo from a statefulset or something similar to all pods at the same time.
Can anyone tell me how to do that?
Thanks

I tried to do this with configmap like this:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/modify-elastic-yml-file-in-kubernetes-pod/103612

but when I restarted the pod it threw an error:
`/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/run.sh: line 28: ./config/elasticsearch.yml: Read-only file system`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized, that you don't even have to edit elasticsearch.yml to set the path.repo setting, you can add it as an enviromental variable in your statefulset like this:

```
env:
- name: path.repo
  value: "/mnt/backup"
```

Answer (score 1):

ConfigMaps are mounted to pods as read-only filesystems, this behavior cannot be changed.

If you want to be able to modify config once for all pods then you have to mount config/ directory as a ReadWriteMany persistent volume (NFS, GlusterFS and so on).

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?
I've tried setting claimtemplates in my statefulset like this:
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: config
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
but aplying this threw errors

Comment: That's because probably your PersistentVolume does not support ReadWriteMany mode. You need to find or deploy yourselves volume provisioner that is capable of doing that (NFS, GlusterFS). You may try that: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-server-provisioner

Answer (score 0):

In version 6.8 the config file is in a secret.
I was unable to change the secret to update the base64 encoded configuration.
However, apparently the way to configure it is to set it as documented here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-node-configuration.html

the yaml file is the one that can be found under Object Browser:

[screenshot object browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5LhA.png)

from the command line you can use :

```
kubectl get -o yaml Elasticsearch elasticsearch-name-of-your-deployment > your.yml
```

Then mod it and apply it with

```
kubectl apply -f your.yml
```